# Relational Database: DELETE versus "Mark for Deletion"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Recently, I stumbled about the following problem: Given is a simple data model with "Books" and "Authors". Each "Book" has a reference to an "Author". Persistence is achieved with a relational database. Besides adding books and authors, it is also possible to delete them. Usually, if I want to delete an Author, i would perform a SQL `DELETE` operation and remove the corresponding row. However, I have seen in other projects, people don't call `DELETE`. Instead, they add some kind of active/deleted flag and mark the corresponding row as "deleted".

My questions are: Is this in general best practice? What are the advantages? My best guess is:

- Setting a flag has a better performance than a `DELETE` operation
- If you run out of space, it is still possible to run a cleanup service which looks for deleted object and removes the corresponding rows
- Setting a delete flag is better for database consistency because a deletion of "Author" in the example above could destroy foreign keys in the corresponding "Book entries.

Anyway, these are just guesses. Does someone know the answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many reasons to not use `delete`.  First, maintaining history can be very important.  I wouldn't use "just" a delete flag, but instead have dates of validity.

Second, in an operational system, `delete` can be an expensive operation.  The row needs to be deleted from the table, from associated indexes, and then there might be cascading deletes and triggers.

Third, `delete` can prevent other operations from working well, because tables and rows and indexes get locked.  This can slow down an operational system, particularly during peak periods.

Fourth, `delete` can be tricky to maintain relational integrity -- especially if those cascading deletes are not defined.

Fifth, storage is cheap.  Processing power is cheap.  So, for many databases, deleting records to recover space is simply unnecessary.

This doesn't mean that you should always avoid deleting records.  But there are very valid reasons for not rushing to remove data.